# Swagger Downloads "text/csv" as *.txt not *.csv

Tags: javascript, csv, express, swagger

I have a Swagger where I make calls to an Express server hosted locally. The `content-type` is set to `text/csv` and the swagger is set up to accept `txt/csv`, but the file extension when using swagger's "Download" button returns a `response*.txt` file. I need the download have a `.csv` extension, how do I go about doing that? Do I make modifications to my swagger or my express, or both?

Express:

```js
res.status(200).header('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
```

Swagger:

```yaml
produces:
  - text/csv
responses:
  '200':
    description: OK
    text/csv: {}
```

**Note:** I don't want to set the `Content-Disposition` header as `attachment; filename="*.csv"`, since this removes the ability to also *display* the response body as well as have the option to download.

I would like to both display the CSV response as text and have the ability to download as `.csv`.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you :D

Comment: Pretty sure content disposition is the only way to specify a file name

Comment: I'm not concerned about the name, only the file extension. If the `content-type` is set to `application/json` for example, swagger knows to append the `.json` extension.

Comment: @p32094 And if that's the only way, how do I also get it to display the text? When I use it it only has a download file option